# Ionic2 @ViewChild unexpected token

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have followed this link to create a Slider. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/slides/Slides/

However, when I try to access the local template variable using ViewChild it gives me an error.

`Unexpected token (10:44) while parsing file: /Users/shawn/Desktop/Ionic/abcdefg/app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.js`

These are my source codes

**dashboard.html**

```js
<ion-content>
 <div class="black-mask">
  <div class="calendar">
   <ion-slides #calendarSlider (didChange)="onSlideChanged()" [options]="slideOptions">
    <ion-slide>
     <div class="calendar-cell" *ngFor="#cal of previousCalendar; #i = index" [ngClass]="{selected: cal.selected}" (click)="toggle('previous', i)">
      <span class="calendar-day">{{ cal.dayOfWeek }}</span>
      <span class="calendar-day-number">{{ cal.day }}</span>
     </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
     <div class="calendar-cell" *ngFor="#cal of currentCalendar; #i = index" [ngClass]="{selected: cal.selected}" (click)="toggle('current', i)">
      <span class="calendar-day">{{ cal.dayOfWeek }}</span>
      <span class="calendar-day-number">{{ cal.day }}</span>
     </div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
     <div class="calendar-cell" *ngFor="#cal of nextCalendar; #i = index" [ngClass]="{selected: cal.selected}" (click)="toggle('next', i)">
      <span class="calendar-day">{{ cal.dayOfWeek }}</span>
      <span class="calendar-day-number">{{ cal.day }}</span>
     </div>
    </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
  </div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

**dashboard.js**

```js
import {Page, NavController, Slides} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {LoginPage} from '../login/login';
import moment from 'moment';

@Page({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
 queries: {
  calendarSlider: new ViewChild('calendarSlider')
 }
})
export class DashboardPage {
 @ViewChild('calendarSlider') calendarSlider: Slides;

 static get parameters() {
  return [[NavController]];
 }

 constructor(nav) {
  this.nav = nav;
  console.log(this.calendarSlider);

  // Calendar Slider Options.
  // 0: Previous
  // 1: Current
  // 2: Next
  this.slideOptions = {
   initialSlide: 1,
   loop: true
  };
        (.......)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you use ES6 instead of TypeScript. With ES6 you need to leverage the `queries` attribute of the `@Page`:

```
@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
  queries: {
    calendarSlider: new ViewChild('calendarSlider')
  }
})
export class DashboardPage {
  (...)
}
```

**Edit**

The `calendarSlider` is set before the `ngAfterViewInit` callback is called. So you can access the value in this method (and after).

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.calendarSlider);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thierry, it did not work after adding the queries to the page.

Comment: I'm still getting Unexpected token

Comment: It works on my side. On which line does this error occur?

Comment: Unexpected token (13:44) while parsing file. I added queries inside @Page decorator.

Comment: Okay and you removed `@ViewChild`?

Comment: What do you have on line 13?

Comment: Line 13 is the ```@ViewChild```. If I remove ```@ViewChild```, there isn't any errors but calendarSlider is undefined

Comment: You can't use the `@ViewChild` decorator in ES6. When / how do you try to access `calendarSlider`. You could try within the `ngAfterViewInit` hook method. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Wow, after adding the ngAfterViewInit() method, it works! I am able to access ```this.calendarSlider```. Any idea where I can read up more on this? Thanks Thierry!

Comment: See this links: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html (query decorators)